# 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, x86, apt

I install nodejs using NodeSource repository, I followed instruction mention on [deb.nodesource.com](https://deb.nodesource.com) (on home page), after installing whenever I am running `sudo apt update` I am getting this warning at the end of output, and nodejs is working fine, So my questions is why it is showing this error and how could I fix this issue?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

My system's informations are:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Processor: AMD A6-7310 with Readon R4 Graphics

I searched for solutions and read other similar question's answeres but they were specific about those errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning itself is fairly harmless. It's just saying that the node repo doesn't have any 32 bit packages. I suspect at some point 32 bit support was added to this Ubuntu install. You can check by looking at:

```
# dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

and

```
# dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

and see if any multi-arch arches are set. You can force any given repo to only care about one architecture by tweaking the deb line. So in your case edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` to read:

```
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg, arch=amd64] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro main
```

Comment: Thanks, @stsquad it's worked, and removed the warning.